Integracion Auth0 en Flutter
Estoy desarrollando en Flutter por primera vez y tengo que integrar el login de Auth0.
Me cree una cuenta en Auth0, cree una organización y una aplicación.
Siguiendo el manual: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/flutter/interactive
Configure mis callbacks urls, llegando a que mi emulador Android redirija a la página de login de auth0 de mi aplicación, pero la pantalla queda en blanco:

Si ingreso por chrome desde mi navegador, llego OK al login, pero desde el emulador no puedo y ya no se por donde seguir.
Ví que hay que configurar en Auth0, en configuracion avanzada - Device Settings, el package name y el Key Hash, pero intenté generarlo desde la terminal y no me reconoce el comando "keytool" y no sé si efectivamente es eso lo que esté fallando.
No sé cuanta más información puedo dar para guiar sobre esto ya que tampoco puedo confirmar que esto es lo que me falta.
Cualquier información es bienvenida
